# Greatest number of consecutive vowels

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a String and returns the greatest number of consecutive equivalent vowels in the String.

Here's my attempt:

```
public static final String VOWELS = "aeiou";

public static int consecutiveVowelsInLine(String line) {
    int longestVowels = 0;
    int candidateLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (isVowel(line.charAt(i))) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(i+1)) {
                candidateLength++;
            }
        } else {
            candidateLength = 0;
        }
        longestVowels = Math.max(longestVowels, candidateLength);
    }
    return longestVowels;
}

public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    VOWELS.contains(c.toLowerCase());
}
```

The problem is this doesn't handle the case where the `String` is a single character that's a vowel. So if the String is just `"a"`, my code gives back `0` instead of `1`.

As said before, the vowels have to be the same.

**Testcases**:

```
a    -> 1
b    -> 0
ae   -> 1
aeae -> 1
aab  -> 2
aba  -> 1
abee -> 2
```

Comment: Do the vowels have to be the same? What if you take as input `ae`, does this count as two?

Comment: Does this code compile? My IDE shows a "Cannot invoke toLowerCase() on the primitive type char" error for `c.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Is 'y' not a vowel? ;-)

Comment: @Dominique It depends on language.

Comment: @CommuSoft Sorry; it must be the same vowel, so "ae" does not count as two.

Comment: @bclayman: I've edited your question a bit such that it is more clear what you ask. Can you confirm that the semantics are correct?

Comment: @CommuSoft They're correct, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you aim to do too much in the loop: instead of looking to the character next, concentrate on the current character and *maintain a state* that stores the previous vowel:

```
public static int consecutiveVowelsInLine(String line) {
    int longestVowels = 0;
    int candidateLength = 0;
    char vowel = 'b'; //b is not a vowel
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        char ci = line.charAt(i);
        if (isVowel(ci)) {
            if (ci == vowel) { //the same as the other one
                candidateLength++;
            } else {
                candidateLength = 1;
            }
            vowel = ci;
        } else {
            candidateLength = 0;
            vowel = 'b';
        }
        longestVowels = Math.max(longestVowels, candidateLength);
    }
    return longestVowels;
}
```

Here `vowel` stores the current vowel sequences you are working with. In the beginning we use `b`, simple because that is not a vowe. In case we encounter a vowel, that vowel is stores in `vowel` and we update the `candidateLength` accordingly. In case we encounter a non-vowel, we set vowel back to `b` (or another non-vowel).

**Demo**:

There were some problems with your `isVowel` method as well, a running implementation with a few testcases can be found [here](http://jdoodle.com/a/xg).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one problem:

```
    if (line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(i+1)) {
        candidateLength++;
    }
```

If the string is only one character, you're checking the character against null.  Add a check, something like this:

```
if (line.length() == 1 && isVowel(line.charAt(0)) {
    etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change it like:

```
public static int consecutiveVowelsInLine( String line ){
        int result = findConsecutiveMaxValue( line );
        if( result == 0 ){
            result = findSingleVowel( line );
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static int findSingleVowel( String line ){
        for( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ ){
            if( isVowel( line.charAt( i ) ) ){ return 1; }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private static int findConsecutiveMaxValue( String line ){
        int longestVowels = 0;
        int candidateLength = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++ ){
            if( isVowel( line.charAt( i ) ) ){
                if( line.charAt( i ) == line.charAt( i + 1 ) ){
                    candidateLength++;
                }
            }
            else{
                candidateLength = 0;
            }
            longestVowels = Math.max( longestVowels, candidateLength );
        }
        return longestVowels;
    }
```

Comment: What about words which have only one consecutive vowel, like the word "word"? This code would still give 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I've changed my code for your way, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
        if (line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(i+1)) {
            candidateLength++;
        }
```

to:

```
        if (candidateLength == 0 || line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(i-1)) {
            candidateLength++;
        }
```

Additionally the condition in for() loop looks suspicious - use `getLength()` instead of `getLength()-1`.

Comment: See the [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357718/greatest-number-of-consecutive-vowels?noredirect=1#comment56457111_34357718).

Comment: The requirement *is* to have the sequence of the same vowel

Comment: To be fair to @Zbynek, that wasn't clear at the time they posted their answer. But again, to be fair to the rest of us, if there is any uncertainty, that must be cleared up via commenting, prior to committing an answer.

Comment: @bclayman: Ok, I updated the answer. Please also check the condition in for loop.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000: mind that the question does not mention `i-1`, but `i+1`...

Comment: @CommuSoft: This is correct, it's much simpler to write this condition looking back rather than looking forward when we really don't have full information, isn't it?

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000: yes but you state it as *chance X to Y*, but *X* is already something different.